# How do I open different activities when receiving notification from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

In my app there are different categories, a main page(MainActivity), comments activities and Chat activity etc.
When i receive a notification, either from comments, Chat or main page, it still opens main activity. What I want is if I receive a notification regarding Chat it should open chat activity and if regarding comments it should open comments activity and so on...
Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your [message notification data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), add property `click_action` with value of an action string.  For the activity you want to start, update your manifest to define an intent filter that matches the action.

For example, with message:

```
{
  "to": "dhVgCGVkTSR:APA91b...mWsm3t3tl814l",
  "notification": {
    "title": "New FCM Message",
    "body": "Hello World!",
    "click_action": "com.example.FCM_NOTIFICATION"
  },
  "data": {
    "score": "123"
  }
}
```

Define the intent filter like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyFcmNotificationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.FCM_NOTIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked but there a small problem, there are a lot of comments activities since there are a lot of posts how do i direct to specific comment activity?

Comment: It's difficult to provide specific recommendations.  If you want multiple instances of a comment task, you should look into [activity launch modes and tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).  It's complicated, but you should be able to find settings that meet your needs. The subject has also been [discussed a lot on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+launch+mode).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is `PendingIntent`. You will need to send in the FCM payload the type of notification (chat, comments etc.,) and then in your `onMessageReceived()` you process the notification, know the type and create a PendingIntent using the desired activity. When users clicks on the notification, android will launch the activity specified in the PendingIntent. Refer to this [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html). I hope this helps.

[Update] I like [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123548/5796780) better but I've never tried it myself

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity onCreate() you need to get the intent that started the activity and retraive the data from notification.

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null && bundle.get("data")!=null) {
        //here can get notification message
        String datas = bundle.get("data").toString();
    }
```

From here you can redirect the user depending on data you received from notification.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded

> Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app
>
> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your
>   launcher Activity.

Comment: Am sorry i still don't get it?