# How to pass Latitude and Longtitude from (FCM) push notification to an Android activity

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

**All i want to do is to pass latitude and longtitude as notification and by clicking it, to open Android Google Maps on that location. I have read many posts but i couldn't figure it out, if i have to pass the coordinates as URL or something and be passed to my application Activity  **

To open the activity (SomeActivity) when my push notification is clicked (to use the CLICK_ACTION), i use Postman.

```
{
  "to": 
    "/topics/NEWS"
  ,
  "data": {
    "extra_information": "TestProject"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "NEW INCIDENT",
    "text":  "Opening Google Maps",
    "click_action": "SOMEACTIVITY"
  }
}
```

The Java file is:

```
package com...;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by User on 2/23/2017.
 */


public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_activity_layout);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + "40.589352" + "," + "23.030262"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Your help would be appreciated and will definitely make my day !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open Google Maps and show a marker on a location by sending the lat/lng as properties of `data` rather than `notification`.  For example:

```
{
  "to": 
    "/topics/NEWS"
  ,
  "data": {
    "title": "NEW INCIDENT",
    "lat": "37.8726483",
    "lng": "-122.2580119"
  }
}
```

Then, in your message service, get the data and generate the notification yourself:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage msg) {
        super.onMessageReceived(msg);

        Map<String, String> msgData = msg.getData();
        Log.i(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + msgData);

        if (msgData != null) {
            postNotification(msgData.get("title"), msgData.get("lat"), msgData.get("lng"));
        }
    }

    private void postNotification(String title, String lat, String lng) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat + "," + lng));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_STATUS)
                        .setContentInfo(lat + '/' + lng)
                        .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        NotificationManager mgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mgr.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

If you've written your own activity that displays a Google Map using [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment),  then you can invoke it using `click_action` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123548/4815718).